# Get rewritten URL with query string

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, url-rewriting, query-string

I'm using tuckey URL rewriting with JSF.

I would like to get the relative URL including parameters that the user sees:
e.g.

```
example.com/mypage?param=test
```

At the moment if I do

```
#{view.viewId}
```

I get

> mypage.xhtml

what I want to get is:

> mypage?param=test

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`UIViewRoot#getViewId()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/component/UIViewRoot.html#getViewId--) returns the JSF view ID. You need to use [`HttpServletRequest#getRequestURI()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getRequestURI--) to obtain the current request URI and [`HttpServletRequest#getQueryString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getQueryString--) to obtain the current request query string.

```
#{request.requestURI}#{empty request.queryString ? '' : '?'}#{request.queryString}
```

Or, if it's a forwarded request, get it as a request attribute keyed with [`RequestDispatcher.FORWARD_REQUEST_URI`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html#FORWARD_REQUEST_URI) and [`RequestDispatcher.FORWARD_QUERY_STRING`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html#FORWARD_QUERY_STRING) respectively:

```
#{requestScope['javax.servlet.forward.request_uri']}#{empty requestScope['javax.servlet.forward.query_string'] ? '' : '?'}#{requestScope['javax.servlet.forward.query_string']}
```

Clumsy yes. Consider hiding away in `<c:set>` of a master template, or an utility tag/function.

Comment: This doesnt work...it shows mypage.xhtml?param=test, I want to display the rewritten URL mypage?param=test